# How can I process all the HTML tags in a document without blocking?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that gives users the ability to manipulate the appearance of websites based on simple rules about the site content. The problem is that I have to scan and classify every tag in a document, a potentially slow process. I'm looking for a way to do this without blocking the page rendering and slowing down the user's experience too much.

Right now my content script looks something like this:

```
function init() {
  tagObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, obs) {
    for(var i=0; i<mutations.length; ++i) {
      for(var j=0; j<mutations[i].addedNodes.length; ++j) {
        var newTag = mutations[i].addedNodes[j];
        if (newTag.querySelectorAll) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(
            newTag.querySelectorAll('*'),
            testTags);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('*'),
    testTags);
  tagObserver.observe(document.documentElement, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });
}

function testTags(tag) {
  sleep(5);
  tag.style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
  tag.style.color = '#FFF';
}

function sleep(ms) {
    var date = Date.now();
    var curDate = null;
    do {
        curDate = Date.now();
    } while (curDate-date < ms);
}

init();
```

In this case, `testTags` is a placeholder function representing the actual, possibly slow, classification code. If I use this, it slows down the rendering of each page astronomically. How can I pull as much out of the rendering path as possible to keep page drawing fast enough for the average user? It is acceptable if the tags take some time to classify, but I don't want to wait until the page is completely done rendering before even beginning to modify anything.

Comment: Two things: first, challenging the core assumption -- why do you have to examine every single tag? It seems like there would be an easier way to identify only those elements that are important to you and restrict your work to those elements. Could you look at all the textNode elements and check the contents of that, then act only on the parent nodes if the textNode is identified as interesting? Second, a spitball idea -- could you treat the HTML as a string to do a quick-and-dirty analysis of the tags as a first pass to identify target elements that need modification? You could use regex....

Comment: the reason it's slow is your "sleep" function (which won't even work like you want because JS is single threaded, so the dom won't update before or after the "sleep", use a timeout

Comment: @ChrisBaker I want to examine every tag because I have a lot of different categories that tags can fall into. For example, all tags that have background-images applied to them through CSS, tags that have more than X children, etc.

Comment: @dandavis Did you read the whole question? I'm not using a sleep.

Comment: i focused on the code... you should only need one mutation observer, they can observe subtrees/children. that will help, but what you want to do will slow the page down quite a bit, no way around it other than waiting (either by the user or code)

Comment: @dandavis What do you mean, I "should only need one mutation observer?" Right now that is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Hmm. You might still be able to do a quick-and-dirty regex parse against the HTML, treating it as a string. That would get you part of the way there, but not with 100% reliability. The only other thing I can think of is to use Web Workers, which I am not certain is available in the extension environment. Should be? That would at least help your longer loops not block the UI thread. Another alternative might be to segment the nodes: you'd count them, divide them into small chunks, then use a queue/timeout to handle the chunks in batches, which would give the UI thread breathing room.

Comment: Wondering if you made any progress on this?

Comment: @ChrisBaker I'm afraid not. Regex parsing the HTML won't help me much. Web Workers cannot modify the DOM, which is part of what I need to do. Developing a homegrown way of batching and queuing jobs in order to periodically yield to the UI rendering would probably work, but it adds a lot of extra complexity which makes me a touch nervous.

I was hoping this was a solved problem, but it looks like that's not the case.